# Using IEclipseContext in an RAP Application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-rap

we try to use single sourcing in an RCP/RAP-Application.
The RCP-Application works fine, and we try now to use RAP for the webfrontend.

For example the following class

```
public class NavigationProcessor {
    //...
    @Inject
    private IEclipseContext context;

    @Inject
    private MApplication application;

    @Inject
    private EModelService modelService;
    //...
}
```

uses the IEclipseContext. But after setting the target to RAP the namespace `org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.IEclipseContext` can't be resolved.

How can i access IEclipseContext after setting the target to RAP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, RAP only supports the Eclipse 3.x workbench.
There are experiments towards running [Eclipse 4 applications on RAP](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/16/eclipse-4-applications-on-rap/).
Unfortunately, Eclipse 4 still has a [number of issues](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392977) that prevent using it in multi-user environments.